# can I load external project's java classes at runtime using reflections or any other method

Tags: java, reflection

can I use java reflections api or org.reflection api to load java classes at runtime in an external project which is not in our class path? can someone answer me if there is any other way to load extenal java classes at run time

Comment: There is the URLClassLoader; one could use the file URIs: "file:/.... .jar". More plugin oriented would be the OSGi system with modules and defined life cycles.

Comment: Here's an example how we dynamically load plugins using URLClassLoader in our application: https://github.com/taconaut/ums-mlx/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/pms/plugins/PluginsFactory.java#L247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load classes with the reflection api that are not in your actual project or under the classpath.
For example, this works with the `URLClassLoader`.

To load more than one file as asked in the comments, you can iterate over the files in a directory. For each file you can use the class-loader.

You can get the files of a directory by using the file-class. For example:

```
Path p = Paths.get("");
File f = p.toFile();
String[] files = f.toAbsoluteFile().list();
```

Then you have a string-array of the files/directories. If you are in the directory containing your class-files, you can just iterate over the array and load them one after another by your ClassLoader

Comment: I have already done that , but my application wants to load java classes in a package and want to read specific. Annotations in that java classes, how can I achieve that , cz jar file contains the .class files ?

Comment: I am sorry but i do not really understand what your implementation shall do. Or to put it another way, what it shall do with the annotations.

Comment: Okay let me know that , how to load multiple classes inside a jar using reflections. Cz for name() method takes exactly one class name .

Comment: I edited above. For a more specific answer please post something of your code